# Calling SKYPE API directly via URL

Tags: java, api, skype, skype4java

I am new to SKYPE.
I am wondering that can we call SKYPE API directly from URL?
I found a thread asking something like that.

> [Can you retrieve your Skype status using JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261163/can-you-retrieve-your-skype-status-using-json/6248847#6248847)

*Facebook, twitter,etc provide their API expose to developers to make direct call from app.*

**Is it possible to make direct API call in SKYPE?**

thanks.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://skype.sourceforge.jp/index.php?Skype%20API%20For%20Java%20(English)) ?

Comment: [The Skype Public API](http://developer.skype.com/accessories)

Comment: @Jigar I already try this library. but seems like I need to install Skype client in my machine and limited to per user whom I log in. how can we instantiate for multiple users?

Comment: @Andreas_D are u referring to this public API? [link](http://developer.skype.com/accessories)   As far as I tested I need to install Skype client in my machine and limited to per user whom I log in. how can we instantiate for multiple users?

Answer (score 1):

Grace,

I would suggest you to make a RESTFul Web Service and use the Skype API on the server side.
You can easily expose all the Skype Services by exposing the different URLs.

JAX-RS using JAXB annotation will help you use JSON based communication between your browser and Web Service.

Hope it might help you.

Comment: Note that this will only work if the Skype API works inside the web server.

Comment: eCuTeR thanks for the quick reply.I tested with SKYPE public API [link](http://developer.skype.com/accessories).are u referring to this public API? As far as I tested I need to install Skype client in my machine and limited to per user whom I log in. how can I instantiate for multiple users?

Comment: Yes, Skype API will be on the server. And call web services to use the API.